# I'm a beginner in Java so have struck in problem. What does (i +1) mean in the statement of a for loop for creating matrix program?

Tags: multidimensional-array

Like I have some example about my question, it goes somthing like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter Row "+ (i+1) + " :");
```

In above last line => `+ (i+1) +`

Answer (score 1):

It is appending the value of `i + 1` to a string then appending  `:` to that result. So it would end up printing

```
Enter Row 1 :
Enter Row 2 :
Enter Row 3 :
```

The reason for the parentheses is because of precedence. Without them you would append `i`, then append `1` resulting in

```
Enter Row 01 :
Enter Row 11 :
Enter Row 21 :
```